# Paperclip preserve_files option defined with proc / lambda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I was trying to define preserve_files option of the Paperclip with a Proc object like that:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :asset, styles: {
                          thumb: "100x100#"
                        }, 
                        preserve_files: Proc.new { |image| Image.where(asset_fingerprint: image.asset_fingerprint).where.not(id: image.id).any? ? true : false }

 end
```

but it behaves like it was returning always "true". **Is there a way how to define it properly?**

The point is that files with the same fingerprint are saved on the storage only once but the file itself cannot be deleted if another saved Image object is using it.

Comment: Quick answer, as far as I know, you cannot pass a `Proc` to `preserve_files`. It accepts a `Boolean` only.

Answer (score 1):

The `preserve_files` option defines if the file should be saved or removed when deleting the object it belongs to.

From the [paperclip documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#file-preservation-for-soft-delete):

> This will prevent `some_attachment` from being wiped out when the model
>   gets destroyed, so it will still exist when the object is restored
>   later.

The functionality that you describe (saving images only once when uploaded to several objects) is really interesting although is not included on paperclip.

Comment: This functionality can be added over paperclip interpolations. E.g. option `url: "/system/images/:md5_path.:extension"` where :md5_path is the interpolation which makes the path and filename from the fingerprint of the file. In fact, image is uploaded and saved always (so the fingerprint like md5hash can be calculated) but it is stored only once. Some reference solving similar issue: http://jonathanng.com/ruby-on-rails/getting-around-ext3-inode-limitations-using-md5-file-paths-and-paperclip-interpolations/